# refresh my piechart using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a piechart drawn using matplotlib. Alongside this pie chart i have a slider, which when pressed will invoke a handler. I would like this handler to change the values of piechart. So for example, if the pie chart has labels 60% and 40% respectively, i would like the labels to be modified to 90% and 10% upon the slider being pressed. Here is the code:

This draws the pie chart and slider:

```
plt.axis('equal');
explode = (0, 0, 0.1);
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=underlyingPie, colors=colorOption,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
plt.axis('equal')

a0 = 5;
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
aRisk  = axes([0.15, 0, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
risk = Slider(aRisk, 'Risk', 0.1, 100.0, valinit=a0)
risk.on_changed(update);
```

and the following is the event handler, the desired functionality is to modify labels and redraw the pie chart

```
def update(val):
    riskPercent = risk.val;
    underlyingPie[0] = 10;
    underlyingPie[1] = 90;
    plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=lab, colors=colorOption,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
```

i am also drawing the below, can i get both the pie chart and the below on the same canvas?

```
fig = plt.figure();
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211);

for x,y  in zip(theListDates,theListReturns):
    ax1.plot(x,y);

plt.legend("title");
plt.ylabel("Y axis");
plt.xlabel("X axis");
plt.title("my graph");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: to redraw the pie chart with new values when the slider is invoked

Comment: I gathered that, but your code looks more-or-less correct, what is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty much what you're looking for. You need to have an axis handle for the pie chart in order to keep modifying it in place.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

x = [50, 50]

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3)

# draw the initial pie chart
axarr[0].pie(x,autopct='%1.1f%%')
axarr[0].set_position([0.25,0.4,.5,.5])

# create the slider
axarr[1].set_position([0.1, 0.35, 0.8, 0.03])
risk = Slider(axarr[1], 'Risk', 0.1, 100.0, valinit=x[0])

# create some other random plot below the slider
axarr[2].plot(np.random.rand(10))
axarr[2].set_position([0.1,0.1,.8,.2])

def update(val):
    axarr[0].clear()
    axarr[0].pie([val, 100-val],autopct='%1.1f%%')
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

risk.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: hello aganders3, many thanks for your response, your solution works perfectly, the only addition is that i am drawing another graph on the same canvas i want the piechart on, any chance we can do that? I have modified the code above to illustrate

Comment: You should open another question if your needs change significantly. You should have no problem drawing another plot in the same figure, however. Just change the `plt.subplots` parameter depending on how many you need to draw.

Comment: i have a new question, i would really appreciate it if you can take a look - 19545485/different-figures-on-different-canvases-using-matplotlib